# javascript assign property statement to return parent object

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I am trying to get something like this:

```js
// instead of having to write
a.b = 'c'; return a;
// i'd like to write
return a.b = 'c';
// but this will return a.b instead of a
// a (cumbersome) alternative is
return Object.defineProperty(a, 'b', {value: 'c',
                                      enumerable: true,
                                      writable: true,
                                      configurable: true})
// or using a shorthand function
function set(target, property, value){
    return Object.defineProperty(target, property, {value: value,
                                             enumerable: true,
                                             writable: true,
                                             configurable: true});
}
return set(a, 'b', 'c');
```

I'd be more interested in some way of overloading the `=` or even the `.` operator but I don't know if that's possible or how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that.

You can write a simple helper:

```
function set(target, property, value) {
    target[property] = value;
    return target;
}
```